# What quotes can I use while coding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

Can I always use backticks or not and why?
I noticed that people often have single quotes, although the functionality of backticks is more.

Comment: Backticks imply that this is a template string or a multiline string. I would think that this is a mistake if it was just a regular string.

Comment: Exactly, you can use always backticks is you prefer.

Comment: Certain constructs like the [`import` statement](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) require strings with `"` or `'`. Be aware of that.